# How to set up protractor for my E2E testing?

Tags: protractor

I am new to Protractor, i want to learn protractor for Angular application. could someone help me to set up protractor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The website has a guide on how to do just that. [Here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Protractor is an end-to-end test framework for AngularJS applications built on top of WebDriverJs. Protractor can be run as a standalone binary runner or included into your tests as a library. Use Protractor as a library if you would like to manage WebDriver and your test setup yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this site ([here](http://www.webdriverjs.com/learn-protractor)) useful for you:

Comment: Much useful link for beginner !

Comment: Check this - [protractor](https://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2019/05/27/getting-started-with-the-protractor/)